# Automatizar un código Python en Mac o en cloud

Tags: python

Muy buenas,

He creado un script en Python que necesito que se ejecute de manera recurrente todos los días. 
Pero querría saber cuál creéis que es la mejor opción para hacer esto si realizar un daemon con alguna librería, o bien hacer que se ejecute automáticamente con algún programa.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres una solución 100% de python, podrías crear un archivo aparte que ejecute tu script como un subproceso:

- Creas un bucle infinito con esta lógica.

  - Comprobamos si el minuto actual coincide con el que queremos.
  - 1. Si coincide, ejecutamos el script y dormimos el bucle durante 23 horas (es inutil realizar comprobaciones a cada hora si solo queremos ejecutarlo una vez al día).
       **Nota:** En este ejemplo suponemos que el script pueda tardar menos de una hora en ejecutarse.
    2. Transcurrido ese tiempo, hace comprobaciones cada 30 segundos para ver si la hora actual coincide con la hora a la que queremos ejecutar el código.
  - Si no coincide, comprobamos cada 30 segundos hasta que coincida.

Que en código queda así:

```
from time import sleep
from subprocess import call
import datetime

hora_de_ejecucion = "10:00"

while True:
    hora_actual = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")  
    if hora_actual == hora_de_ejecucion:
        call(['python', 'nombredelscript.py', arg1, arg2...]).
        sleep(1380)
    else:
        sleep(30)
```

Es importante mencionar que el código de sleep no funciona mientras se está ejecutando un subproceso (creo), por lo que tenlo en cuenta a la hora de adaptar los tiempos que necesites (por eso es necesario una comprobación de tiempo, en lugar de simplemente decir al programa que duerma 24 horas).